# PHP modify $_SESSION values in tests

Tags: php, session, testing, legacy-code

I need to test a PHP Web-Application. The Application is one block of procedural code (in index.php), controlled by session variables. Determined by control-flow, other files are included that are procedural blocks of php, too (xy.inc) and modify session variables. E.g.:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
session_name("some_name");
session_start();

$_SESSION['some_key'] = 'some_value';
if($_SESSION['key1'] == 1){
  //include some file that in the end sets $_SESSION['key1'] = 0 
}
else if($_SESSION['key2'] == 1){
  //Do something
  $_SESSION['key2'] = 0;
  $_SESSION['keyX'] = 'someOtherControlValue';
}
//....Lots of code
$SESSION['whatever'] = 'justAnotherValue';
//..more code, more $_SESSION checks and so on
```

Refactoring is no option (at the moment?), so I'm just trying to get at least some basic tests running, without interfering with the coder's "programming style".

Is there a way of accessing (and modifying) the $_SESSION properties in acceptance tests?
I want to use [Codeception](http://codeception.com/) for my tests (but I'm open for alternatives).

I want to achieve something like (pseudo)

```
// setup test db etc.
get('/');
assert(title == 'the title');
// change some control values
$_SESSION['myDatabase'] = 'myTestdb';
$_SESSION['SomeKeyForFuctionIWantTest'] = 'myValue';
get('/');
assert($_SESSION['SomeKeyForFuctionIWantTest'] == 'myValue');
assert(getSomeElementCreatedByFunction() != null);
assert(somethingIsInTheDatabase);
```

I have little experience in php and session-management (and I'm coding in OOP), can anyone help me out?

side-note: There is no framework, mvc or anything else involved

Comment: Do you want to change the session data in mid-execution or would loading a different set on session_start() suffice? In the first case: Really? Why? In the latter case: maybe writing and setting up another [session handler](http://docs.php.net/session_handler) will do the trick.

Comment: @VolkerK:
I need to read and write session-values after visting a page (so the php got executed already), like 
1. read session and modify var x
2. load page '/', which uses var x and sets some other vars
3. read session and modify var y
4. load page '/' (...)
I have to be aware of the current state between page loads (state of session)
Could you give me a minimal example on how I can integrate a custom SessionHandler in the index.php? Is it just calling session_set_save_handler() in the class or do I have to modify the index.php to actually use the class?

Answer (score 0):

I found a relatively simple and very dirty hack for this.

When testing I'm not calling '/'(index.php) directly, but a test page.
The test page sets my variables as needed (maybe need a "safe" way to inject my test vars here..).

```
# defined in /test.php - otherwise change path in include index
<?php
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");   
   header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    
   header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

   session_name("my_session_name");
   session_start();

   $_SESSION['TESTME'] = 'bla';

   session_write_close();
   session_destroy();

   include 'index.php';
?>
```

In index.php I can see $_SESSION['TESTME'] == 'bla'.

Fight fire with fire I guess..